# How to pass multiple Java objects into Javascript (Rhino)

Tags: javascript, java, mozilla, rhino

How do I structure a ScriptableObject to be able to achieve this

```
functon onRequest(request, response, modules) {
  var requestBody = request.body; 
  response.body = request.body;
  response.body.hello = 'world';
  response.complete(200);
}
```

Where everything inside the `onRequest` Javascript function will be the *expression*:

And the `request`, `response` and `modules` are Java objects passed to the Javascript runtime to be accessed.

```
        Context cx = Context.enter();
        ScriptableObject scope = cx.initStandardObjects();
        cx.evaluateString(scope,
                String.format("function onRequest() { %s }", expression),
                "<func>", 1, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question is to pass the Java Object through:

```
ScriptableObject.putProperty(scope, "foo", fooObj);
```